# Java - Parse List<Field> into String

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I'm trying to turn a `List<Field>` into simple strings, but I'm not sure how to parse them out of the array into a single `String` variable.

I'm currently using a method that goes through a class that uses a `getDeclaredFields()` method and outputs them into an array.

```
public static List<Field> getInheritedPrivateFields(Class<?> type) {
    List<Field> result = new ArrayList<Field>();

    Class<?> i = type;
    while (i != null && i != Object.class) {
        Collections.addAll(result, i.getDeclaredFields());
        i = i.getSuperclass();
    }

    for(Field temp : result) {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The result I get when I output it is

```
[private int com.gen.e.ric.report.domain.TestCount.count,
 private java.lang.String com.gen.e.ric.report.domain.Test.facility, 
 private java.lang.String com.gen.e.ric.report.domain.Test.technology,
 private java.lang.String com.gen.e.ric.report.domain.Test.component, 
 private java.util.List com.gen.e.ric.report.domain.Test.etestStats, 
 private java.util.Date com.gen.e.ric.report.domain.Test.startDate, 
 private java.util.Date com.gen.e.ric.report.domain.Test.endDate]
```

What I want to get is just a long string with

```
int, String, String, List, Date, Date
```

Any help to give? Using Reflection btw.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use `toString()` method to convert your fields into String.

Comment: @Maxouille that's what already happens when he's calling `System.out.println(temp);`.

Comment: @f1sh I agree but I don't understand what is really asked here. Do we only want values like `facility`, `technology` etc as string or a `List<String>` containing the type of the attributes, or a concatenated String with all types ?  ?

Comment: @Maxouille read `What I want to get is just a long string with`

Comment: @f1sh my bad -_- srry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only want to output each `Field`'s type, so do that:

```
for(Field temp : result) {
    System.out.println(temp.getType());
}
```

or in order to put it into a `String`:

```
String types = result.stream().map(e->e.getType().getSimpleName()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 3):

The output format is like that as `Field` class `toString` method implemented like below:

```
public String toString() {
    int mod = getModifiers();
    return (((mod == 0) ? "" : (Modifier.toString(mod) + " "))
        + getType().getTypeName() + " "
        + getDeclaringClass().getTypeName() + "."
        + getName());
}
```

> Note: `Class & Field` class both are `final` so you `can't override`
>   it also.

So, you can't change the toString definition of Field. But what you can build your own String like below:

```
String s = result.stream().map(e -> e.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `getSimpleName()`. For eg:

```
String.class.getSimpleName();
```

In your example all you need to do is :

```
for (Field temp : result) {
    System.out.println(temp.getType().getSimpleName());
}
```

---

So your method will now look like :

```
public static String getInheritedPrivateFields(Class<?> type) {
    List<Field> result = new ArrayList<Field>();

    Class<?> i = type;
    while (i != null && i != Object.class) {
        Collections.addAll(result, i.getDeclaredFields());
        i = i.getSuperclass();
    }

    return result.stream()
                 .map(field -> field.getType().getSimpleName())
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Field.getType()` to get the `Class` of the `Field`, then use `Class.getSimpleName()` in order to get only the part you want :

```
List<String> types = new ArrayList<>();
Field[] declaredFields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field declaredField : declaredFields) {
    // Will give [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, int]
    // types.add(declaredField.getType().toString()); 

    // Will give [String, String, int]
    types.add(declaredField.getType().getSimpleName()); 
}
System.out.println(types);
```

> [String, String, int]